# In platonscript where in my unit i have to write the address of my web server which receives my web service?

Tags: xml, soap

I am writting code in jPlaton and i want to create a unit that will send a web request to our Web Server and then it will receive some data from our database.

I have found a sample unit and i made some changes but i can not understand where to put our server web address.

Comment: What kind of request are you trying to send? Is it a web service? XML SOAP or REST? Please be more specific

Comment: I want to send a soap request for a web service.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a SOAP service you should use

```
SOAP
...
...
ENDSOAP
```

in order to create your XML SOAP Message and then use the following command:

```
SENDSOAP "YOUR_URL:PORT/SOAP_DEFINITION" SOAP_OPERATION
```

This will send your message to the URL defined in the provider's WSDL and call the SOAP_OPERATION